# what does [length] after a `\\` mark mean

Tags: spacing

what does \[length] mean? like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
mmmmm\\[-0.33em]
mmmmm

mmmmm

\hspace{-0.33em}mmmmm
\end{document}
```

why are these do not render the same?

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, LaTeX commands can take both required and optional arguments. Required arguments are (generally) enclosed by curly braces, while optional arguments are enclosed by square brackets.

Next, if the string

```
mmmmm\\[-0.33em]
```

occurs inside an `array` or a `tabular`-like environment, the sub-string `\\` is the instruction to insert a line break and `[-0.33em]` represents an *optional* argument to the `\\` instruction. If the argument, which is supposed to be a length, is a positive, additional vertical whitespace -- in the amount of that argument -- will be inserted; it it's negative, that amount will be subtracted from the default amount of vertical space that's inserted by `\\`.

(Aside: If you use `\\` *outside* of `array` and `tabular`-like environments, it's quite likely that you're doing something wrong...)

In contrast, `\hspace` is a text-mode command that serves to insert or subtract *horizontal* space. Incidentally, to LaTeX, `\hspace{0pt}` is *not* the same as "doing nothing" -- inserting "zero-length whitespace" can have significant and (if used correctly) very handy use cases.

In short, there's no reason to believe that `\\[-0.33em]` and `\hspace{-0.33em}` would, let alone *should*, produce the same outcome.

Comment: I see this in `pkuthss`, it is in a `section` like `    \section*{mmmmmmmmm \\[-0.33em]\textmd{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}}`, so it should be equal to a line break plus `\vspace{-0.33em}`?

Comment: @Firestar-Reimu - I guess it's a way of creating a subheader, in non-bold font weight, on a line *below* the main section-level header. I deliberately used the qualifier "quite likely", as there's no rule without an exception, right? For sure, though, the vast majority of uses of doble-backslash in postings to TeX.SE, outside of `array` and `tabular` settings, do not serve such a legitimate purpose...